# LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands -- Only one of either

Tags: packages, document-classes

I am using RStudio to work with RMarkdown files to generate PDFs.

In `test.Rmd`, I have:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "John Doe"
# date: "Jan. 17, 2018"

output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3                    # default = 3
    number_sections: true           # add section numbering to headers
    fig_width: 6                    # default = 6
    fig_height: 4.5                 # default = 4.5
    fig_caption: true               # default = false
    highlight: tango                # specifies the syntax highlighting style
    includes:
      in_header: doc_prefix.tex
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
linkcolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
citecolor: blue
---


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

In `doc_prefix.tex`, I have:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
```

That's it. Yet I'm getting the error: `LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands`. I see no duplicates of either, nor one of each. What gives?

Comment: Haven't used Rmarkdown, but presumably it adds a documentclass for you, so when you add a second one manually you get two.

Comment: As I said, this isn't something I use, but is the documentation in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-options relevant here, or is it for something else?  If it is relevant, try adding `documentclass: IEEEtran` in the header options, e.g. right after `fontsize: 11pt`.

Comment: you fail to inform us how you are processing your files to get to your error message.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That documentation is relevant. Can you provide an example header with indentation? Also, how should `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` look in this Markdown context? I tried several variations but couldn't figure out the indentation and formatting.

Comment: Well, judging by those docs, the `documentclass` option is the same level as the `fontsize` option, so same indentation (i.e., no indentation). As for adding `conference`, I can only refer you to that same documentation - try with `classoption: conference`.